# Is the contents of .svn folder standardised and cross-compatible between SVN-clients?

Tags: svn

Can I for example use one svn client to create a WC and another svn client to commit that WC?

This has worked for me before, but is it guaranteed to work?

The actual case here is the problem of offline work. The checkout needs to be done by one machine and the work on the WC on another. It would be valuable for the offline machine to still manipulate the WC (adding/removing files etc) instead of working with an "export" and then merging the work on the machine with the SVN-repo.

I've looked around for information regarding this but I haven't found any. If you have an answer it'd be great if you have a source reference as well.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the format is dictated by the server, not the client so you should be fine, but I don't have hard reference either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of the working copy is defined by the client. Usually you can checkout a working copy via SVN client (1.1) work on the WC with a client (1.2) and so on but not the other way. Checkout out with SVN client (1.4) and committing via SVN client (1.5 or 1.6) after that the working copy has been upgraded to WC format 1.5 or 1.6 which means you can't access the working copy via SVN client 1.4 anymore. The server does not define the format of the working copy. Cause you can access a SVN repository (for example 1.2 repository) via a SVN client 1.6 ...(some functionallaty does not work) but committing etc. is working fine (see [release notes of 1.6](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html)).

Comment: +1 But this means that two different client products (like say, Tortoise and Ankh) that use the same client library can access the same WC, correct?

Comment: @Pekka Accessing a svn WC with tools of the same version should work. The main problem is that a newer client will automatically update a WC without any confirmation or note.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the same version of subversion linked into your clients then it is guaranteed to work. This is because the clients do not operate directly on the WC, but do so through the subversion 'library'.

Now, there can be an issue with clients that are linked with different versions of subversion, I noticed this back when I upgraded TortoiseSVN that used the new version 1.6 subversion libs, but still used the old AnkhSVN that was linked to v1.5, as a result Tortoise automatically upgraded the WCs which meant Ankh no longer recognised them. A quick download of the updated Ankh fixed that, but it was annoying for a few days while the Ankh team released their new version.

so - yes, all clients use the same format of WC, but when upgrading (to major versions of svn, going from 1.6.11 to 1.6.12 will not break anything, but going from 1.6.12 to 1.7 will) wait a little while so all your clients can release their new versions.