# SVN format compatibility between old and new clients

Tags: svn, ubuntu-14.04

I have few dev machines running ubuntu 13.10 with SVN client 1.7.9 planing to update to ubuntu 14.04 LTS which has SVN client 1.8.8. on a trail I got following error from 1.8.8 SVN client( 14.04 ).

```
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: The working copy at '/path/to/working/copy' is too old (format 29) 
to work with client version '1.8.8 (r1568071)' (expects format 31). 
You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

from this error and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html I understand that, I need to run

```
svn upgrade
```

on my SVN 1.7.9 working copy.

my question is,

Does format31 (1.8.8) working copy work with format29 (1.7.9 client) after I commit some changes to and checkout in other machines (which still running 1.7.9 client).

will upgrade affect the working of older clients?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you can use different versions of clients (and formats of WC) at the same

Working Copy is **local only** part of Subversion: Subversion client must to use compatible with it format of WC (can't read older and can't read newer).
When you commit, all changes stored in repository (which haven't such strict restrictions, BTW) and from any *other clients* changes will be transferred to corresponding Working Copy of *any version*

Comment: Thank you!.thats a relief!..and now I understand client is BerkeleyDB based. 
could you explain or direct me how it is stored on server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460321/is-the-contents-of-svn-folder-standardised-and-cross-compatible-between-svn-cli?rq=1 explains this..only now I found this from related questions part!..